# Why is my :focus not working? I have linked the CSS to the HTML properly, but also the input is not styled as per the stylesheet

Tags: html, css, hover, focus, web-deployment

This is just an example. I wanted the border of input to be rounded when it is clicked. But it did not happen.

```css
.username {
    border-radius: 0%;
}
.username :focus{
    border-radius: 30%;
}
```

```html
<input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username or Email">
```

Comment: Get rid of the space between username and focus. `.username:focus{}` the pseudo may be `:active` actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the space between username and focus. `.username:focus{}` the pseudo may be `:active` actually.

```
.username:active {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, getting rid of the space worked. Change:
.username :focus {}
to
.username:focus {}

Comment: Your answer is right, but it must be comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is like this.

```css
    .username {
        border: 2px inset;
        border-radius: 0px;
    }
    .username:focus {
        border-radius: 10px;
        outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<input class="username" type="text" placeholder="Username or Email">
```